# How to retrieve the private key of a user certificate?

Tags: windows, certificate, private-key

I want to retrieve the private key of a user certificate under Windows.
I use the CertOpenSystemStore and CertEnumCertificatesInStore methods to retrieve the user certificate.
Then the CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey method to retrieve the private key but there is a problem with the access rights.
Is this the right way to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

The Certificate of a User Account is not stored in the 'Computer Store', if you need permissions on a key stored in the Computer store, you need to:

1. run `certlm.msc`
2. navigate to the certificate
3. right click > 'all Tasks' > 'Manage Private Keys ...'
4. set your desired permissions

If the certificate is in a user store, you must impersonate that user and access its personal store. In this case, you can export the key if the key is marked as exportable.

If the key is generated by a PKI, there is also the possibility that the key is available at the PKI but this depends strong on the configuration of the PKI